# перегрузка метода с ArrayList<Integer>() на ArrayList<String>()

Tags: java, generics

В общем решал задачу:

> Считать по ключу с файла строки или целые числа, отсортировать и записать в другой файл.

Стал писать и решил я сделать метод сортировки ArrayList в аргументах.

Ну и решил я его значит перегрузить и один сделать `sort(ArrayList<Integer> array)`, а второй `sort(ArrayList<String> array)`.

Ну и тут то Intellij IDEA меня и обломала с сообщением:

> fix method 'sort' parameters with bounded wildcards

Как понимаю компилятор видит, что в обоих случаях есть ArrayList, а тип хранимых в нем значений его не волнует.

Но информации не нашел, а как спросить у гугла и не знаю. Он меня завел не в те дебри.

Может кто объяснить почему все же так происходит или может ресурс какой, где про это написано по подробнее.

Буду благодарен за любые ответы.

Comment: не до конца понял задачу. Есть файл, в нем строки.  Что вам нужно сделать с строками в файле? запарсить? и что мешает назвать методы по разному?

Comment: Задача простая, сортировка входных данных. И её я решил. Вопрос был направлен на то, что бы получить ответ, почему не сработала перегрузка. В итоге дал методам разные имена и все. И ответ мне Anton Shchyrov в итоге дал, за что ему спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java принята модель дженериков со стиранием типов. Т.е. конкретный тип существует только на этапе написания кода. А при компиляции все дженерик-типы стираются и остается только абстрактный Object.

В итоге ваши объявления

```
sort(ArrayList<Integer> array)
sort(ArrayList<String> array)
```

преобразовываются в

```
sort(ArrayList array)
sort(ArrayList array)
```

и компилятор вам честно сообщает, что у вас объявлено два идентичных метода

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А где можно по подробнее про них почитать, а то как то сколько статей попадалось, этот момент как то не освещался

Comment: @КонстантинКотов Хорстманн детально описывает этот механизм

Comment: @AntonShchyrov у Эккеля тоже неплохо раскрыто)